# Error when using broom (augment) and dplyr with loess fit

Tags: r, dplyr, broom

I am trying to use augment on a loess fit, but I receive the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 32, 11
```

In the error message, 11 happens to equal the number of observations in one segment and 32 is the total number of observations. The code is below.

```
require(broom)
require(dplyr)

# This example uses the lm method and it works
regressions <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>%  do(fit = lm(wt ~ mpg, .))
regressions %>% augment(fit)

# This example uses the loess method and it generates the error
regressions2 <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>%  do(fit = loess(wt ~ mpg, .))
regressions2 %>% augment(fit)

# The below code appropriately plots the loess fit using geom_smooth. 
# My current # workaround is to do a global definition as an aes object in geom_smooth`
cylc = unique(mtcars$cyl) %>% sort()
for (i in 1:length(cyl)){
  print(i)
  print(cyl[i])
  p<- ggplot(data=filter(mtcars,cyl==cylc[i]),aes(x=mpg,y=wt)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="loess") + ggtitle(str_c("cyl = ",cyl[i]))
  print(p)
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This appears to be a problem related to the `do()` operator: when we check the `model.frame()` on one of the LOESS model objects, we get back all 32 rows rather than the subset corresponding to that model.

A workaround is to hold on to the data and not just the model, and pass that as the second argument to `augment()`:

```
regressions2 <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(fit = loess(wt ~ mpg, .),
     data = (.)) %>%
   augment(fit, data)
```

This is usually recommended with `augment()` anyway, since `model.frame()` doesn't get all the original columns.

---

Incidentally, I'm the maintainer of broom and I generally no longer recommend the `do()` approach (since dplyr has mostly been moving away from it).

Instead, I suggest using tidyr's `nest()` and purrr's `map()`, as described in [this chapter of R4DS](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html). This makes it a little bit easier to hold on to the data and incorporate into `augment()`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

mtcars %>%
  nest(-cyl) %>%
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~ loess(wt ~ mpg, .))) %>%
  unnest(map2(fit, data, augment))
```

Comment: Thank you David for your detailed response. I read up on that chapter and the solution is crisp and sensible. You may want to consider updating the vignette here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html, as this is where my use of do() originates.

Comment: @Steve you are entirely right! There are some new plans and resources for maintaining broom that mean those updates are likely to happen this summer

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: As a reproducible solution, add library(tidyverse), library(broom).